# Permission Problems with KextManagerLoadKextWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, macos, permissions, kernel-extension

I'm trying to reload a kext in an Objective-C OSX application I'm writing. The KextManager API seems to be what I should use (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/KextManager_header_reference/Reference/reference.html))

Calling `KextManagerUnloadKextWithIdentifier()` works flawlessly, but when I go to load the same kext shortly after using `KextManagerLoadKextWithIdentifier()` I get this console error:

```
com.apple.kextd[12]: Request from non-root process 'App Name' (euid 501) to load /path/to/kext - not allowed.
```

The docs for both methods both state "The calling process must have an effective user id of 0 (superuser)", yet unload works and load does not? Surely they should both behave the same?

Comment: This seems like something you should raise in a bug report to Apple. By the sound of it, the API is working as advertised, it just happens to also work in one case where according to the documentation, it won't. So I suggest you use it as per the documentation (call as root user) in your app.

Comment: How would you call as a root user in an app? From the research I've done it's impossible now due to Apple's security  changes in the way apps can be built (deprecated APIs and Sandboxing)

Comment: You can't do it from an App Store app. The App Store rules specifically disallow dependency on kexts. Outside the app store, you can use an on-demand launchd daemon to run as root. (or use one of a bunch of other ways of running helper programs as root)